# Changing a Tabs Location in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to be able to click the HTML div button and relocate the current tab.

***redirect.js***

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
        url: "http://www.roblox.com/"
    });
});
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
  <script src="redirect.js"></script>
</html>
```

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "z",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "z",
  "background": { 
     "page":"popup.html"
     },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
     "js": ["redirect.js"]
   }
   ],
  "permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "<all_urls>",
  "unlimitedStorage"
]

}
```

Those are my current scripts, it doesn't let me use onclick when I add a div button, I need that help mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: you did not specify the browserAction in the manifest.json. If you want to use  chrome.browserAction.onClicked, you have to specify a browser action. add an extension icon.

2: you do not need content script

3: if you only want a single redirect function, you do not need to request bookmarks and all urls and storage permissions.

so here is your manifest.json should be :

```
{
  "name": "z",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "z",
  "background": { 
     "page":"popup.html"
     },
   "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
  "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {                    
        "19": "icon.png"  //you have to put an image icon.png in to the folder.                 
      },
      "default_title": "Redirect" //optional 
   }

}
```

Then it will works.

plus, do not name your background file as "popup.html", popup usually used as a popup window.

you can also download the extension here, only this script will redirect to google after click. you can modify it yourself.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-gxNl6LTj5jdkZPTm9qQXB4S1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: modified, also added a downloadable link.